# MS sync framework 2.1 - Delete on client without affecting server

Tags: frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using the Sync framework 2.1 to sync multiple SQL Express databases to a central database server over a WCF service. It works fine. Now I have a requirement that certain records in a table in the client database (source) which is set to "upload only" need to be deleted as part of archiving but it should not delete the corresponding records on the server (destination). Please note that the records would already have been synced. How can I do this with the Sync framework, like restrict the sync only for new records and deletes should not be synced. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should be possible, you can intercept the changes from the source on the Changes Selected event and remove the rows you don't want to sync to prevent them from flowing thru the destination.

have a look at this post : [Manipulating Change Dataset in SyncFx](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/)